# Concat a string with a function to get a JSON output

Tags: java, spring

I just started using java for a project, and I have this doubt. I'm trying to get a JSON answer with this code, but I don't know how to concatenate a string with a function in Java Spring. I have this controller, with this result:

```
public class BbController {
    @Autowired
    BbService bbService;

    private static final String RESP_SUCCESS =  "{\"result\" : { \"status\": true, \"http_code\" : 200, \"info\":  \"list successfully obtained.\"}}";

    @RequestMapping(value= "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getAllContracts() {
        return RESP_SUCCESS +  ",{" + this.bbService.getAllContracts() + "}";
    }
}

<---------- RESULT --------->>>
{
    "result": {
        "status": true,
        "http_code": 200,
        "info": "list successfully obtained."
    }
},
{
    [com.example.entity.BbEntity@3ddd5cfb, com.example.entity.BbEntity@1a57ff51
    ]
}
```

Without the concatenation and just returning return this.bbService.getAllContracts(), the output would be

```
[
    {
        "id": 12345,
        "id_client": 123,
        "n_contracts": 2,
        "default_number": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id_client": 12,
        "n_contracts": 2,
        "default_number": 2
    }
]
```

My service would be

```
public class BbService {
    @Autowired
    BbDao bbDao;

    public List<BbEntity> getAllContracts(){
        return this.bbDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this result?

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": true,
        "http_code": 200,
        "info": "list successfully obtained."
    }
},
{
  [
    {
        "id": 12345,
        "id_client": 123,
        "n_contracts": 2,
        "default_number": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id_client": 12,
        "n_contracts": 2,
        "default_number": 2
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `this.bbService.getAllContracts()` returns a class that does not implement `toString()`, therefor it gets this ugly default print, you can implement it to get the better represenataion that you want.

But I think the better solution should not be to fix the toString, but rather to change the return value of your method from a string to some class you create. If you're using spring, it will be serialized into json once you do it

Comment: Can you give me one example? I'm really new with java and java spring and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: read this tutorial- https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ . you can see there how they return an object, it will get serialized as you like

Answer (score 0):

if `this.bbService.getAllContracts()` , `getAllContracts()` returns the class it self, it will be autamatically serialized into Json.